# UK international travel restrictions November 2020

Tags: uk, international-travel, legal, uk-citizens, covid-19

Regarding the latest international travel restrictions, the UK government has said that all international travel is banned, unless for 'legitimate' reasons. Obviously a holiday etc would be off the table.

My issue is that I am going abroad to sell a property, and the date of signing with the buyers has been set for the 25th of November 2020, when the sale will be finalised. I have to be there in person and I have booked my tickets in accordance.

My question is, does this count as a legitimate reason to travel abroad, as long as I can present the legal document of property sale with the date on?

Answer (score 6):

Not a lawyer, but I think it makes a difference whether this is a personal or business transaction. If the latter, and you "have to be there in person" then it seems to me to be allowed under https://www.gov.uk/guidance/new-national-restrictions-from-5-november#travel :

> 11. Travel
>
> If you live in England, you cannot travel overseas or within the UK,
> unless for work, education or other legally permitted reasons, and you
> should look to reduce the number of journeys you make. However you can
> and should still travel for a number of reasons, including:
>
> - travelling to work where this cannot be done from home
> - [etc]

If however it's a personal transaction, I think you'd need to go looking at the actual definition of that 'legally permitted', which I found [here](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/1200/made). It seems to me you might have a case under 6 (2) (g):

> [you can legally leave your home]
>
> (g)to undertake any of the following activities in connection with the
> purchase, sale, letting or rental of a residential property—
>
> (i)visiting estate or letting agents, developer sales offices or show
> homes;
>
> (ii)viewing residential properties to look for a property to buy or to
> rent;
>
> (iii)preparing a residential property to move in;
>
> (iv)moving house;
>
> (v)visiting a residential property to undertake any activities
> required for the rental or sale of that property;

That last one covers you if the meeting is at the property. If it's not, you're looking perhaps at the first one. It's all a bit of a minefield.

Comment: It will all come down to  how this regulation is going to be enforced - big difference between a "papers please" regime and a permissive honesty system.